# Change column values based on another column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the table

```
+---------------------+
| ID | Code | Amount -|
+---------------------+
| 1  | 101  | 1.2     | 
| 1  | 102  | 1.3     |
| 1  | 103  | 1.3     |
| 1  | 104  | 1.4     |
| 1  | 105  | 1.2     |
| 2  | 101  | 1.5     |
| 2  | 102  | 1.4     |
| 2  | 103  | 1.3     |
| 2  | 104  | 1.1     |
| 2  | 105  | 1.0     |
+---------------------+
```

What I am trying to do is change the amount column for each ID which is not the code 101 to the value in amount from code 101

So my output should be like this.

```
+---------------------+
| ID | Code | Amount -|
+---------------------+
| 1  | 101  | 1.2     | 
| 1  | 102  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 103  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 104  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 105  | 1.2     |
| 2  | 101  | 1.5     |
| 2  | 102  | 1.5     |
| 2  | 103  | 1.5     |
| 2  | 104  | 1.5     |
| 2  | 105  | 1.5     |
+---------------------+
```

This is clearly a simplified table to show what I need as the row count today is over 100,000 but will change everyday.

I have tried to use a cursor but it is very slow. Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to UPDATE the table, or just adjust a SELECT result?

Comment: There are two values for 101. Any logic ?

Comment: @jarlh Sorry, should of said that. I want to UPDATE the table

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh Yes there is logic. ID 1 has code 101 which has the value 1.2 which is unique to that ID. So all IDs will have the codes 101,102,103,104,105 which will all have the amount which is unique to that ID

Comment: `2  | 101  | 1.2` This looks wrong. Is the amount 1.5 based on your output?

Comment: @ughai. Yes that is wrong. I have updated my question to show it should be `2 | 101 | 1.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update t
set t.amount = t2.amount
from your_table t
join 
(
  select id, min(amount) as amont
  from your_table
  where code = 101
  group by id
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t.code <> 101
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick:

```
DECLARE @t table(ID int, Code int, Amount decimal(6,1))

INSERT @t values
(1,101,1.2),(1,102,1.3),
(1,103,1.3),(1,104,1.4),
(1,105,1.2),(2,101,1.5),
(2,102,1.4),(2,103,1.3),
(2,104,1.1),(2,105,1.0)

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    min(CASE WHEN Code = 101 THEN amount end) 
      over (partition by ID) newAmount,
    Code,
    Amount
  FROM @t
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET Amount = newAmount 
WHERE 
  code <> 101
  AND newAmount is not NULL


SELECT * FROM @t
```

Result:

```
ID  Code  Amount
1   101   1.2
1   102   1.2
1   103   1.2
1   104   1.2
1   105   1.2
2   101   1.5
2   102   1.5
2   103   1.5
2   104   1.5
2   105   1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UPDATE FROM` like this

```
UPDATE Tbl1
SET Amount = Tbl2.Amount
FROM Tbl1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT ID,Code,Amount
FROM Tbl1
WHERE Code = 101
)Tbl2
ON Tbl1.ID = Tbl2.ID
WHERE Tbl1.Code <> 101;
```

**Edit**

If there can be multiple amount values for the same code and ID, `GROUP BY` can be used like this.

```
UPDATE Tbl1
SET Amount = Tbl2.Amount
FROM Tbl1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT ID,MAX(Amount) as Amount
FROM Tbl1
WHERE Code = 101
GROUP BY ID
)Tbl2
ON Tbl1.ID = Tbl2.ID
WHERE Tbl1.Code <> 101;
```

Comment: Not sure who downvoted but was not me.  I didnt even try your code. Answer marked as correct answer worked it just happened to be the one I tried first. But was not me who down voted

Comment: @Sam - It's perfectly fine to mark an answer accepted if it solved your problem even if there are other solutions available that work as well. Not an issue. Downvoting an answer without a comment is useless to the person who answered. He has no way to improve his answer if there is any issue with it (unless the issue is obvious)

Comment: Already said it was not me. I know who the system works. To prove it I can down vote it if you wish

Comment: @Sam - Yes, I know it wasn't you. The comment was not directed at you. I was merely discussing it with you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Update YourTable
Set Amount = (select top 1 a.amount from yourtable a where a.id = YourTable.id and a.code = 101)
```

**EDIT:**

Check this

```
select *,(select top 1 a.amount from yourtable a where a.id = YourTable.id and a.code = 101) as [your update value]
from YourTable
```

Comment: You answer did not work. It just returned amount the same for all IDs

Comment: Check the edited answer, i forgot to add alias in subquery in update statement.

Answer (score -1):

Use a sub-query to get the 101 amount for the id:

```
update tablename t1 set amount = (select max(amount) from tablename t2
                                  where t1.ID = t2.id
                                    and t2.code = 101)
where t1.code <> 101;
```

No need to update 101 rows, keep them out of the transaction (`where t1.code <> 101`).

`MAX(amount)` is there to make sure only one row returned from sub-query.

Comment: I didnt down vote you. I didnt even try your code. Answer marked as correct answer worked it just happened to be the one I tried first. But was not me who down voted